# jQuery UI passthrough official example: ui is not defined

Tags: jquery-ui, angularjs, angular-ui

I copied the jQuery passthrough example from here http://angular-ui.github.com to this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ilyaD/Xe48t/3/ and it is not working. I am getting `ui is not defined`

this is the JS:

```
angular.module('ui.config', []).value('ui.config', {
   // The ui-jq directive namespace
   jq: {
      // The Tooltip namespace
      tooltip: {
         // Tooltip options. This object will be used as the defaults
         placement: 'right'
      }
   }
});
```

what did I miss?

UPADTE:

I added `ui` to `angular.module('ui.config', ['ui']).value('ui.config', {` but still not working http://jsfiddle.net/Xe48t/9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you're not supposed to declare the value on the `ui.config` module. You declare it on your own app and it will take precedence:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ui']).value('ui.config', {
  jq: {
    // whatever
  }
});
```

Note that this is defined on `myApp`

It also helps if you:

- run your JS in the right place (head)
- have AngularJS initialize properly (using `ng-app`)
- and load the bootstrap lib and css

http://jsfiddle.net/Xe48t/12/

Comment: muchas gracias! although I have a few questions: what is `ui.config`? and what is value? couldn't find good explanations...

Comment: `ui.config` is a way to specify app-wide default options for any AngularUI directive (or passed-thru plugin). In other words, you _could_ do `ui-jq="tooltip" ui-options="{theme:'custom'}"` or even `ui-options="customConfig"` every single time you call `ui-jq="tooltip"` **or** you could simply define the app-wide defaults in `ui.config` and move on with life.

In my opinion, it's very awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're including the AngularUI javascript file, and then you want to use the string "ui".

```
angular.module('ui.config', ['ui'])
```

Comment: it was included in the dependencies, but to make it clearer I updated with all includes at the top of the html http://jsfiddle.net/ilyaD/Xe48t/3/

Comment: You also need to use the string "ui" and not a variable ui. See my updated answer.

Comment: I am suppose to see the text I fill in the content of the textbox in the tooltip, right? if so it still doesn't work http://jsfiddle.net/ilyaD/Xe48t/5/

Answer (score 0):

You missed the ui dependency:

```
angular.module('ui.config', ['ui']).value('ui.config', {
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Xe48t/4/